# Access ListView model within the Repeater component in the delegate

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, repeater

I am using a `ListView` with a model and a delegate.

The model is a simple `ListModel` with three items. Each item has a value with the key `myFirstRole`.

The delegate contains a `Repeater` component to create an arbitrary number of `Labels`. The `Labels` have to use data from the model.

The model of the repeater **can not** be set to the `Listview`'s model as I have the `Repeater` using other data.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
//MyDelegate.qml
Component {

    Item {
        id: root

        width: childrenRect.width
        height childrenRect.height

        Repeater {
            model: 5 //It's not an option to set the repeaters model to the ListViews model. This example just illustrates my problem.

            Label {
                text: root.ListView.view.model.myFirstRole //This is the line where I want to be able to access the ListView's model, but I can't figure out how to properly reefer to it.
            }
        }
    }
}

//MyListView.qml
ListView {
    id: root

    delegate: MyDelegate {}
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "one"
        }
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "two"
        }
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "three"
        }
    }
}
```

Using Qt 5.7.0 with MSVC2015 32bit

Comment: Your example isn't complete. I see no `ListView` at all but you mentioned that in title.

Comment: @folibis: I did not think it was necessary as the ListView code for this example is not anything but standard boilerplate ListView code. I can add it for completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can't access the roles via the special `model` property mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models) (which is what I'm assuming you were trying to do) from the scope of the `Repeater`. Instead, you can declare a property at the root level of the component that can then be used in nested scopes:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { myFirstRole: "Dog" }
            ListElement { myFirstRole: "Cat" }
        }

        delegate: Item {
            id: root

            width: childrenRect.width
            height: childrenRect.height

            property string myFirstRoleData: myFirstRole

            Repeater {
                model: 5

                Text {
                    text: myFirstRoleData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might get a bit tedious if you have a lot of properties though. From some quick playing around, it looks like it's also possible to store the entire `model` object in a property:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { myFirstRole: "Dog" }
            ListElement { myFirstRole: "Cat" }
        }

        delegate: Item {
            id: root

            width: childrenRect.width
            height: childrenRect.height

            property var modelData: model

            Repeater {
                model: 5

                Text {
                    text: root.modelData.myFirstRole
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`modelData` is probably not the best name to use though, seeing as Qt uses that name for models with only one role, but... if you're going with this approach, you're gonna have more than one role anyway. :)

It looks like Qt Quick Controls' (1) `Tumbler` [does this too](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/extras/Tumbler.qml#n389).

Comment: I did try this exact thing, but it did not work. I will try again and report back if it was just me getting tired...

Answer (score 1):

```
//MyDelegate.qml
Item {
    id: root
    property var listViewModel // pass the model data to here
    width: 100
    height: 50

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: 5 // Use a different model here
            Text {
                width: 50
                height: 10
                text: listViewModel.myFirstRole //This is the line where I want to be able to access the ListView's model, but I can't figure out how to properly reefer to it.
            }
        }
    }
}

//MyListView.qml
ListView {
    id: root
    width: 100
    height: 500

    delegate: MyDelegate {
        listViewModel: model // set the model data here
    }
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "one"
        }
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "two"
        }
        ListElement {
            myFirstRole: "three"
        }
    }
}
```

See the comments in the code. It is not trivial to guess what you want to achive, but I hope I guessed right.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but in my original post I wrote a comment in the code that the model of the repeater can not be set to the listviews model. The reason for this is that the repeaters model has a different model it has to use in my program.

Comment: Ok, I will try my next guess. What you wrote in your question is... very confusing.

Comment: So changed it. I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve. I did try something similar, but I will try this out tomorrow. I also changed (hopefully improved) the question.

Comment: Well, actually this solution perfectly suits your needs. listViewModel is just a property, it's not connected to your's delegate.model. So, you still can access your delegate model via modelData.myPrivateData and also your external ListView data via listViewModel.myFirstRole.
So, actually listViewModel isn't a model - it's just an object, that contains data you pass from ListView

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev: Your updated code should work equally well to Mitch's answer. Though I prefer to keep the binding to the listViewModel property within the delegate itself.

Comment: I would rather not. Because in this case you have a file that is not complete, referencing something that is yet to be declared. I try to never reference anything that is not declared within the same file, to I have a clear interface of the object. This way the component is more reusable and testable.

Comment: Further: When ever you declare a property uppon instantiation, you implicitly create a new class. So if you have the same code `MyItem { property [...]` on multiple occasions, you have the same amount of *identical* classes generated. Therefore, you should declare the property in the file where you declare the component, and not in the file where you use it.